# Multiple query on multiple tables

Tags: mysql, join, request

Mysql requests
I would like help with a multiple request that requires a join between three tables.

Basically the request would look a little like this but I'm not sure:

```
SELECT id_order 
FROM order_refund
JOIN ps_orders ON order_refund.id_order = ps_orders.id_order
```

```
INSERT INTO order_refund (id_payment_method)
SELECT id_payment_method
FROM payment_method
JOIN order_refund ON order_refund.id_order = RESULT;
## the result of the request from above... I don't know how to do that...
```

Here they are:

> ps_orders 
>   - id_order - INT 
>   - payment - VARCHAR (which includes the name of the average repayment ex:paypal...)
>
> payment_method 
>   - id_payment_method - INT 
>   - name - VARCHAR (includes the name of these refund methods ex:paypal...)
>
> order_refund 
>   - id_order - INT 
>   - id_payment_method - INT (does not include anything yet)

I want to insert a numerical value in the id_payment_method deorder_refund column and associate it with the associated refund method.

For that I must, 
retrieve the order_refund id_order and compare it with that of ps_orders, if these are identical then I retrieve the associated refund method ( - payment - varchar) (from ps_orders) and compare it with that of - name - (from payment_method) and retrieve the associated id. I return this one in the still blank column ( - id_payment_method - of order_refund) which absolutely awaits an integer.

I have no choice but to do this, I have already tested queries based on INSERT INTO and JOIN but I am a little lost. Anyone have any idea what the wording is?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Insert is for insert new rows  based on you explanation

Seems you are  looking for   an UPDATE based  on the value you have  in  order

```
  update order_refund 
  INNER JOIN ps_orders ON order_refund.id_order = ps_orders.id_order
  INNER JOIN payment_method ON payment_method.name  = ps_orders.payment
      set order_refund.id_payment_method = payment_method.id_payment_method
```